# How to move template constructor specialization to cpp file?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, template-specialization

I am aware of the reasons why the implementation of templates should go to the header. This question is about template specialization. As far as I understand, this setup should work.

header:

```
template<class T>
class Foo {

public:
  Foo(T value) {
      // not specialized
  }
};

template<> Foo<double>::Foo(double value);
```

cpp:

```
// specialization for float
template<> 
Foo<double>::Foo(double value) {
    // special version for double
}
```

usage:

```
Foo<double>(0);
```

However, i get a compiler error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Foo<double>::Foo<double>(double)" (??0?$Foo@N@@QAE@N@Z) referenced in function _wmain
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to move specialized constructor to an implementation file?

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* You are most likely not compiling and linking the code from the .cpp file while creating your executable.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but the file is included in the binary.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: What i mean is, i checked and the file is compiled and linked into the executable. So this is not the problem.

Comment: This looks like a bug in Visual C++ compiler. Compiles and links fine with MingW g++, and then that constructor is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to me like a bug in the Visual C++ compiler, since the code compiles and links and runs fine with MinGW g++, but I'm not sure.

Anyway, the following workaround header code works with Visual C++.

```
#pragma once

template<class T>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo( T )
    {
      // not specialized
    }
};

template<> Foo<double>::Foo( double );
template class Foo<double>;
```